# Post method not working in Laravel resource route

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5.6

I am having problems with a resource type route that I have in my application, in which I pass parameters via POST in my View and when submitting the form to this route, my POST goes as empty. This problem I'm only having with the hosted system, in development environment it works normally. Here is the code snippet where I set my route and the code snippet and output of the View:

Here is my route:

```
Route::resource('/formulariobo', 'BOResgateController');
```

Here is my view:

```
<form action="/formulariobo/{{$o->id}}/" method="post">

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
```

This is the HTML output:

```
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline" value="Confirmar exclusão">
</form>



<form action="/formulariobo/2/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="SEojXDvKFnYJ0FQrqlIJ72nxoOCj7A2QoOUwF6SE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">                               
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline" value="Confirmar exclusão">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "my POST goes as empty" and how you determined this? What happened? What would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Also, is your token value hard-coded into the template like that, or is this just an example of the parsed output?

Comment: I edited the above code to be clearer, and my problem is that the post submitted by the form is arriving empty in the controller that I refine in the route of type resource

Comment: Can you show the code where you determine that the form is arriving empty?

Comment: <?php      

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;    

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;  
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;  
    use Auth;  
    use Image;    

    class BOResgateController extends Controller  
    {    

        public function __construct()  
        {  
            var_dump($_POST);die;  
            $this->middleware('auth');  
        }

Comment: Return array(0) {}

Comment: I have a feeling that you're doing `var_dump()` after the browser is redirected. When you submit a POST request in Laravel, it will redirect the browser back to the same page and do a GET request. This is known as [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Try examining the output of `request()->method()` to make sure it is POST (or DELETE). If not, you're trying to get the POST data after a redirect, which will not work.

Comment: On localhost, the output is string(3) "DELETE", however on the server the output is string(3) "GET"

Comment: So either you're not sending a POST/DELETE request or you're examining it after the browser was redirected.

Comment: I did not understand. I performed the test in development and production environment, and got these two different var_dump returns.

Comment: You will have to make sure you are performing the tests in exactly the same way. I can't see something like this giving a different result depending on the test environment.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the 2 at the end of the url so that

```
<form action="/formulariobo/2/" method="post">
```

turns into

```
<form action="/formulariobo" method="post">
```

Comment: how does controller know the ID if it's removed?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  and also [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). thanks